# Django: UserCreationForm not getting Custom User Class

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-registration

I'm new to Django and I'm running into an odd issue. Using Django 2.2.5 I've created a custom User class, sub-classed from `AbstractBaseUser`.  Other than extending `AbstractBaseUser` the only major change I made was deleting the `username` field and adding my own (won't get into why here).  I've added the `USERNAME_FIELD = "my new username"` to the model as well.

This all appeared to work well and I was able to create users.  I then installed `django-registration`, to use that functionality and when I tried to `makemigrations` I ran into this error:

> 'django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) ("My new username") specified for User`

Now, this didn't make any sense to me since the model clearly has a"My new username" field and I'd specified Django should use my User model in setting via `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. I knew that was working because calling `get_user_model()` in a shell returned my custom model.

Now here's where it gets weird, I was able to trace the issue to `django-registrations`, `RegistrationForm`.  This is a form that subclasses Django's `UserCreationForm`.  When RgistrationForm was loading or whatever during `makemigrations` it was producing the error because the model reference for the form was `django.User` not my custom user model.  `RegistrationForm` does not declare a model and uses `UserCreationForm` model which happens to be `User` from `django.contrib.auth.models`.

Based on what I've read and how `User` is written it should reference my model, via the `swappable` attribute since I've set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and it's supposed to *swap* to the model located in that settings option.  For some reason, though it's not working and I don't know enough about Django to debug further.

I'm very confused by this since `get_user_model()` references the exact same setting and it works.

I've been able to fix this for the moment by editing the `RegistrationForm` model to add `model = "Custom user model` in django-registration's forms.  I'd rather not have to distribute a custom version of this package with the rest of the site at the moment.

Any idea what's going on with `swappable` that might be causing this issue?

Edit 1/27/19: Update I tried sub-classing the relevant `django-registration` classes, but it turns out that simply importing `RegistrationForm` causes the issue.  Importing `UserCreationForm` does not immediately cause a problem but if I try to check `UserCreationForm.Meta.model."My new username"` it provides this error:

> AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'UVI_Handle'

This is consistent with the error above.  At this point I'm not sure how to proceed again.  I could subclass `UserCreationForm`, but none of `django-registration` will pick up on that so there doesn't seem to be a point in using it, since I'll have to copy the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the package code, you should subclass:

> In the case where your user model is compatible with the default
>   behavior of django-registration, (see below) you will be able to
>   subclass RegistrationForm, set it to use your custom user model as the
>   model, and then configure the views in django-registration to use your
>   form subclass. For example, you might do the following (in a forms.py
>   module somewhere in your codebase – do not directly edit
>   django-registration’s code):

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

from mycustomuserapp.models import MyCustomUser


class MyCustomUserForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyCustomUser
```

Above is taken from [here](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.3/custom-user.html), you should also change the urls, which is also described there.

Comment: Well this is why you shouldn't work after being up for more than 18 hours.  You're right that'll fix my issue nicely.  I'd still like to know why django is behaving this way though.

Comment: So turns out this doesn't work just importing `RegistrationForm` or `RegistraionFormCaseInsensitive` causes the error.  The error is being generated by `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm`.